# How to reset to an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So with my code, the question which I'm trying to answer in Javascript is to reset the items in an array, where it's creating a function named empty, and then reset the items inside an array. So far I have tried out pop array and it lists the whole array out, and then I have tried to write it by using array length.

Here is my code set up for this one:

```
function empty(){
  for(var basket = basket.length=0;  basket--);
}
console.log('Reset basket:', basket);
```

Comment: um, firstly, basket would be undefined so an error would throw immediately, secondly, the syntax in that forloop makes no sense :{

Comment: What are you trying to do to `basket`?  Couldn't you just do `basket = []` (or `basket.length = 0;`)?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to replace just the **variable** `basket` with an empty array, simply reassign it:

`basket = [];`

If you need to reset the actual array referenced by the variable, and therefore reset all references to the same array, simply set `.length` to 0.

`basket.length = 0;`

Your syntax though is incorrect. As a function, it would look like:

```js
function empty(array) {
  array.length = 0;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = arr1; // both variables reference the same array
let arr3 = [...arr1]; // references a different array

empty(arr1);

console.log(arr1); // []
console.log(arr2); // []
console.log(arr3); // [1, 2, 3]
```